# jQuery ajax call not working in FF and safari works in IE

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I made a little module to  use a jquery/ajax script on my website. For that I used examples which are on the site and others. The script is working in IE (for a change it works there) but I cannot get it working in FF or safari. Tried a lot of things but somehow it never executes the updatecounter function
I am not a javascript programmer so have no idea where to look. Maybe there are some who know what I am doing wrong
Tried

```
if (Drupal.jsEnabled) {
$(document).ready(function(content) {
$('a.download').click(function () {
// This function will get exceuted after the ajax request is completed successfully
var updatecounter = function(data) {
alert (data.counter); // only in IE this is displayed not in FF or Safari
}
alert(this.href); // this works in all browsers
var urlget = "/counter/get”;
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: urlget,
success: updatecounter, // The js function that will be called upon success request
dataType: 'json', //define the type of data that is going to get back from the server
data: 'js=1' //Pass a key/value pair
});
//return false; // return false so the navigation stops here and not continue to the page in the link .. This puzzles me also. If I put it in the program stops and does not continue
});
});
}
```

Strange thing is if I change the it to :

```
if (Drupal.jsEnabled) {
$(document).ready(function(content) {
$('a.download').click(function () {
// This function will get exceuted after the ajax request is completed successfully
var updatecounter = function(data) {
alert (data.counter); // only in IE this is displayed not in FF or Safari
}
var fout = function(stat, statext) {
alert (stat.readyState);
alert (statext);
}

alert(this.href); // this works in all browsers
var urlget = "/counter/get”;
$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: urlget,
success: updatecounter, // The js function that will be called upon success request
error: fout , // calls when error
dataType: 'json', //define the type of data that is going to get back from the server
data: 'js=1' //Pass a key/value pair

});
//return false; // return false so the navigation stops here and not continue to the page in the link .. This puzzles me also. If I put it in the program stops and does not continue
});
});
}
```

It always goes to fout and displays error code 4 and text error. So the ajax call is working but gives me always and error (only in FF and safari not in IE)

I am trying on this for some hours maybe someone can help me out here
Thanks

Comment: What is the error you get from the `fout` alert?

Answer (score 1):

Did you copy-and-paste that code from your page into the question? Because if so, it's using a `”` (fancy close-quote) rather than a `"` (straight quote) on this line:

```
var urlget = "/counter/get”;
```

I wouldn't be surprised if that were part of the problem, that's not a valid way to terminate the string (an easy mistake to make, though, with some keyboard layouts).

Comment: Checked it and even changed it to single quotes but makes no difference.
It seems something to do with allowing scripts from a domain since it is working under IE and Opera not with firefox and safari. But have no idea yet how to check it and change it.

Comment: @Erald: Very strange. I'm not seeing anything else obvious, whatever the issue is, I don't think it's in the quoted code -- something elsewhere on the page must be having an odd side-effect. Good luck with it.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem -- and my solution was in the variable names.  Safari was fine with me using 'text' as a variable name (sloppy of me, I know), but it gave an error in FF.

I'm posting this not because I think this is necessarily the solution to the problem above, but just in case someone finds this thread and is making a similar mistake.